# Добавить ключ в массив

Tags: php

Имеется массив с названием стран, как к нужному можно добавить ключ selected? Не используя foreach.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count_location] => 2
            [server_location] => RU
            [name] => Russia
        )

)
```

Делаю я так:

```
$location = "RU"; // понятное дело пример
 foreach ($result as $key => $value){
     $result[$key] = $value;
     if($value['server_location'] == $location){$result[$key]['selected'] = TRUE;}  
}
```

Но не уверен что правильно, так как я раньше мучился а потом узнал о array_map.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, как вы опредляете "нужный" элемент? Вы знаете его номер или содержание?

Comment: @NickVolynkin  я думаю так понятнее?

Comment: Строка      $result[$key] = $value; избыточна. Если эти массивы организованы вне бд, то иного решения, кроме как те, либо иные циклы (array_map, тоже считаю циклом) не вижу.

Comment: похоже вы ищете [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: @Grundy а эта функция я так понимаю не работает с многомерным массивом?

Comment: почему? вполне работает [array_filter and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071780/array-filter-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @Grundy вот теперь вижу можно, но не пойму синтаксис. не поможете?

Comment: @wwwplaton, я вообще говоря не совсем пойму что вы хотите сделать, фильтр просто отфильтрует элементы, а из вопроса как я понял элементы нужно изменить

Comment: @Grundy да, я даже привел пример как я делаю. просто меня смущает большое количество foreach вот хочу сократить.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38596/discussion-between-grundy-and-wwwplaton).

Answer (score 1):

Больше информации.
Какие параметры определяют "нужный" элемент?
Если добавить к каждому элементу, то любой цикл подойдёт, без него не обойтись.
`$array[$selectedID]['selected'] = true;`.